# Odoo 10 Action Error : 'web_settings_dashboard.main'

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am developing on odoo 10. when i click to settings app i face with issue says:

```
Action Error
Could not find client action 'web_settings_dashboard.main'.
```

I looked for module 'web_settings_dashboard' in addons(github repository) and it doesn't exist.

I tried to update web module while starting odoo server but it didn't help.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the standard addons folder of your odoo installation in the configuration file (named `odoo.conf`)

The module can be found at the path:

> /home/odoo/addons/web_settings_dashboard/

this is a sample line of the config:

> addons_path = /home/odoo/addons,/home/odoo/odoo/addons

Comment: Thanks for answer, after looking in my odoo/addons path i found web_settings_dashboard module. adding "odoo/odoo/addons" to addons path and updating all modules again didn't help. "odoo/addons" was already in path.